# Display posts of users you follow?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to display posts by users that I follow on a stream page.

I have a post controller which displays ALL posts from any users. Again I only want posts from users I follow to be displayed on the stream page. I created a new controller called 'Stream'. I am having a difficult time trying to get the users posts who I follow to display on my stream index.

Thank you in advance.

**Stream Controller**

```
class StreamController < ApplicationController
 before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
 before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
 before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

 def index
    @posts = Post.where(follower_id: current_user.id, followed_id: current_user.id)
 end 

end
```

**Stream Index**

```
<div class="page-header">
  <center><strong><h1> Stream Page </h1></strong></center>
</div>
```

**Post Controller**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
    @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 40)
  end


  def show
  end


  def new
    @post = current_user.posts.build
  end


  def edit
  end


  def create
    @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update(post_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    def correct_user
      @post = current_user.posts.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to posts_path, notice: "Not authorized to edit this post" if @post.nil?
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:description, :image)
    end

    end
```

**Users Controller**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
  before_action :admin_user,     only: :destroy


   def following
    @title = "Following"
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @users = @user.followed_users.paginate(page: params[:page])
    render 'show_follow'
   end

  def followers
    @title = "Followers"
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @users = @user.followers.paginate(page: params[:page])
    render 'show_follow'
  end


  def index
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 20)
  end


  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    if @user 

      @posts = @user.posts.order("updated_at DESC")
      render actions: :show
    else
      render file: 'public/404', status: 404, formats: [:html]
  end  
  end

  def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "Your account has been deleted."
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to root_path 
  end

  def admin_user
      redirect_to root_path unless current_user.admin?
  end

end
```

**Relationships Controller**

```
class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]


def create
    @user = User.find(params[:relationship][:followed_id])
    current_user.follow!(@user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @user }
      format.js
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @user = Relationship.find(params[:id]).followed
    current_user.unfollow!(@user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @user }
      format.js
    end
  end

end
```

**Migration**

```
class CreateRelationships < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :relationships do |t|
      t.integer :follower_id
      t.integer :followed_id

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :relationships, :follower_id
    add_index :relationships, :followed_id
    add_index :relationships, [:follower_id, :followed_id], unique: true
  end
end
```

Comment: you can do that without additional controller. can you show models or shema.rb?

Comment: @andreydeineko I added both user model and post model. thanks

Comment: can you please elaborate on what is followed_id? thx!

Comment: @andreydeineko I used Michael Hartl to set up my relationships model. It is a composite index that enforces uniqueness of pairs of (follower_id, followed_id), so that a user can’t follow another user more than once. Does that help?

Comment: Would I need to include a new def within my Posts view and input this? Thank you again for the help.

Comment: Anette, truly to say in this question you better wait for someone more strong in rails relation, I am unfortunately not sure what to do here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Relationship**

I'd personally use a scope with an association:

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :posts

   has_many :subscribed, class_name: "Relationship", foreign_key: "followed_id"
   has_many :followers, class_name: "Relationship", foreign_key: "follower_id"
end

#app/models/post.rb
Class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   scope :subscribed, ->(followers) { where user_id: followers }
end

#app/models/relationship.rb
Class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
   #fields id | user_id | follower_id | created_at | updated_at
   belongs_to :user
end
```

This will give you the ability to call the following:

```
#app/controllers/stream_controller.rb
Class StreamController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @posts = Post.subscribed current_user.followers
   end
end
```

--

**Alternative**

An alternative would be as follows:

```
#app/views/stream/index.html.erb
<% current_user.subscribed.each do |followed| %>
    <% followed.posts.each do |post| %>
       <%= post.title %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

--

Whilst I'm not sure if this will work out of the gate, it's the way I'd create the functionality you're seeking. Essentially, you have to be able to pass the "related" users to your query call, which will then return the objects belonging to the followed relation

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, now I'm getting a NoMethodError in StreamController#index with an undefined method `subscribed'. Specifically  @posts = Post.subscribed current_user.followers.

Comment: Sorry - the scope was named incorrectly! Fixed it now

Comment: Ah I missed that as well! Thanks. This returned the error 
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Stream#index
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: relationships.user_id: SELECT "relationships".* FROM "relationships"  WHERE "relationships"."user_id" = ? Specifically for line: <% current_user.subscribed.each do |followed| %>. I'm so close to getting this fixed. I received this error when I tried another way as well.

Comment: Okay - I forgot you've already created your databases. I'll fix my `foreign_key` relations to reflect this

Comment: Thank you! This will be a big help. I've been working on this for a week.

Comment: Okay I'm sure I saw you had a migration file before & I can't find it! Anyway, I updated the `foreign_key` in the `User` model from memory - you'll have to provide more info if it doesn't work again :)

Comment: This worked. Vote up! :) Thank you. But for some reason it is displaying people who are following me instead of users I am following.

Comment: Nice - I just wrote that off my head! Which "method" are you using to get the results? The problem will be with the relation definition

Answer (score 0):

The `post` variable in the stream controller needs to be an instance variable `@posts` to be available in the view, and to match the `@posts` instance variable you have in the view.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was able to get the page set up. However, I am having a difficult time getting the posts to be displayed on the page.

Comment: Are you able to post your relationships between user and follower and followed_users?

Comment: I added the relationships controller. Is that what you needed? Sorry, I'm new to ROR. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I guess it should look @posts = Post.subscribed @user.following instead of  "current_user.followers". This should solve you problem of displaying people who are following you instead of showing users you follow.